# Request always returns unauthorized sent from React-Native to Django

Tags: django, react-native, api, request, fetch-api

i am trying to send a get request from my react-native app to a django api but i always get the error `{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}`.

but when i try this same request on postman everything works, i tried getting the code from postman itself and copied it to my react-native app but its the same unauthorized error [image: request on postman]

this is the code generated from the above postman request and i copy and pasted directly to my react-native app and it throws the above unauthorized message.

also tried the generated code from postman for curl and it works,

Please let me know what i am missing here

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
//you can assume the token is correct
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Token f38be1f33dbb5d6004108990a0a76");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://base_url/api/v1/endpoint", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: Also tried other methods of the request also not working

Comment: Also tried adding other type of headers just in case `myHeaders.append("Accept", "*/*")` `myHeaders.append("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")` but none of them helped

Comment: have you tried making the content type application/json

Comment: and 'Accept':'application/json' just in case

Comment: Yes already tried those same result

Comment: @Jhon, is there maybe something else being sent along with the request maybe some default config the fetch api is adding or something like that, i am not sure its very confusing

Comment: Try setting the header directly by only using an object and not creating a Headers object.

Comment: @Shayan yes already tried that, same result :(

Comment: @KartikeyVaish, same result...whats changed?

Comment: So please provide more information about your Django project like settings, views, and serializers.

Comment: is there something i can do from my side to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with plain object?

```
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Token f38be1f33dbb5d6004108990a0a76'
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  redirect: 'follow'
};
```

Comment: Yes i did, same result

Comment: What is redirect for? Does url redirect to another resource for sending output?

Comment: No, that can be removed actually, i copied that from postman

Comment: @Travis Can you add `'credentials': 'include' ` and  `mode: 'no-cors'` to options and try?

Comment: to the headers?

Comment: No directly inside `requestOptions`

Comment: Same result, unfortunately :(

Comment: Then you have to debug request in backend i guess. Working fine in postman?

Comment: Ya, i guess so...the backend developer is on a break due to Ramadan. Thanks tho.

Comment: what could be the possible problem on the backend, maybe i can give him a suggestion? if you are familiar with Django

Comment: I don't familiar with Django but if you try request in Postman and working fine then it should work in react-native too.

Comment: Ya but i am out of ideas on what could be wrong, Thank you for your time tho.